# How to create switching registry data in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, regedit

Is it possible to do?
Basically I want to make a data check and switch it to different if its matching or switch it back if its not matching by one file

but "reg query" checks existing value, not data

```
IF reg query HKCU\SOFTWARE v/ 123 d/ A goto A
ELSE goto B

:A
add reg HKCU\SOFTWARE /v 123 /d B /f
:B
add reg HKCU\SOFTWARE /v 123 /d A /f
```

probably i am on a wrong path

Comment: You should put value onto variable if you want to get and compare it. `FOR`-command can parse strings then put it's value onto variable. Imagine you have `REG_SZ`-type parameter `123` with any value. Next example shows value reading :`FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE" /V 123 ^|FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET VAR123=%%C`. Then you can use variable `%VAR123%` as you wish: `IF "%VAR123%"=="A" GOTO A`...

Comment: Have you read the help of `reg query /?`? do you know how to use the `/d` switch? have you recognised the `/f` option?